# Converting maven project that uses plugins to a gradle project

Tags: java, maven, gradle, pom.xml, pax-exam

I'm new with Gradle and confused to change maven code to gradle, I get code from [ApacheKarafCookbook](https://github.com/jgoodyear/ApacheKarafCookbook) and want to use gradle as build tool. I tried use ***gradle init*** and its not working.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0.201403182114</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent-integration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertyName>jcoverage.command</propertyName>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com.packt.*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <append>true</append>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How do I change to gradle?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, update and *improve your question*.

Answer (score 0):

`gradle init` will not do auto conversion of maven plugins, phases and targets. You'll have to do that bit by hand. Here's some documentation on how to [setup and use the gradle jacoco plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html).